# 301 redirect index.php?P=

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a redirected website from 'www.example.com' to 'example.com'. Using an entry in the .htacccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When entering the site: www.example.com, the redirection works: http://example.com

However, when entering the subpage: www.example.com/page1.html, the page loads correctly, but the address is: http://example/index.php?P=page1.html.

This is related to the entry to the .htaccess file, which is from the beginning:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/n_(.*)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/n_(.*)+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^n_(.*)[_+?]?$ index.php?p=news&nid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How to deal with 301 redirection to remove 'index.php? P ='

Comment: You need to perform the external redirection _before_ the internal rewriting.

Comment: And a hint: literal dots need to get escaped in RegexPatterns: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]` Typically works without, but only by accident or chance...

Answer (score 1):

I found the script:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

For the page: `http://example.com/index.php` returns `http://example.com/` and works fine.

There is a problem with subpages:

When he writes `http://www.example.com/page.html` he gets: `http://example.com/?p=page.html`